# Google Maps Api V3 - Internet Explorer 7 and 8 - Map Drag Missing Tiles

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Anyone come across the scenario where a map drag in either IE 7 or 8 works, but some of the map tiles are grayed out? Added image to demonstrate this odd behavior:

[image]

This only occurs in IE 7 and 8. Chrome, FF, etc. all work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out. Had to reverse engineer the CSS and HTML because it didn't appear to be a javascript or Google API issue. It turned out the following CSS call was the culprit:

```
div#map img {
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0);
    display:inline-block;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would check to see if the `tilesloaded` event is being fired.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
    console.log("all visible map tiles should be loaded");
});
```

You could also try triggering a map resize to reload the visible tiles after panning.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll test these out.

Comment: Didn't turn out to be Google API related, but do appreciate the response.